# Fetch jsonArray without loop in Android

Tags: java, android, arrays, json

```
{
"jsonArray": [
    {
        "id": "1",
        "person": "Jason",
        "thur": "F",
        "grade": "17",
        "round": "2"
    },
    {
        "id": "2",
        "person": "Joe",
        "grade": "F",
        "score": "16",
       "round": "3"
    }

    ]
}
```

I want to fetch "person" and to store it in to string[], But without any loop.
In iOS I'll do it like this.

```
 NSArray *personArray = [jsonArray valueForKey:@"person"];
```

Comment: and in Android you... **use google before asking**.

Answer (score 2):

In android you can use [Google library called Gson](https://github.com/google/gson)

for example You can create a class like this

```
    private class ClassObj {
        @SerializedName("personA")
        private final String personA;
    }
```

And then parse it

```
ClassObj object = gson.fromJson(jsonString, ClassObj.class);
```

`ClassObj` can contain other sub classes too ;)

Comment: Thanks for your answer, May I know why this question get down votes.

Comment: yes, just take a look at this [**guide**](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: I can't find out where I do mistake. Please help me.